# How to make modules/library resources private android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-library

I do according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources)

module common created

res/values/public.xml

```
<resources>
   <public name="app_name" type="string"/>
</resources>
```

Also tried

```
 <resources>
    <public/>
 </resources>
```

res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
  <string name="app_name_2">app_name_2</string>
</resources>
```

Also tried without public.xml

res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
  <public name="app_name" type="string"/>
   
  <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
  <string name="app_name_2">app_name_2</string>
</resources>
```

```
<resources>
  <public />
  <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
  <string name="app_name_2">app_name_2</string>
</resources>
```

module app can use private resources

```
android.example.common.R.string.app_name_2
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from Android Developers side, because their [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Rox-HXhRfI&t=144s) says how private resources should work, but they don't work that.

That's why I created an [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262588970) request, everyone who is affected can vote (upper right corner) so that Google pays attention to the error.